# Boolean value in React input default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input

I have a controlled checkbox input, for which I should set default value from my request, but I've got an error "Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'". Maybe you know how to avoid this?

```
<input
   {...register("car")}
   type="checkbox"
   defaultValue={data.car ? true : false}
/>
```

Comment: the error is literally telling you whats wrong. you can instead try assigning 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultChecked` property in `input` element.

For example:

```
<input
  {...register("car")}
  type="checkbox"
  defaultChecked={data.car ? true : false}
/>
```

Comment: Or it can be just this ?

defaultChecked={data.car}

Comment: Of course, it's available.